# Are questions about AI history on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in the evolution of neural networks. Therefore I would like to ask questions like "Who was the first to describe a perceptron with more than one output node?" Are these kind of historical questions on-topic here?

Comment: I don't feel confident I know enough about what is, and isn't, appropriate on this site to tell you if a question about AI history would be on-topic here. However, in case you didn't know about it, although I'm not an expert there either, I'm reasonably confident that, if appropriately worded, such a question would be on topic at the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE site, as AI is basically part of computer science. Nonetheless, if you decide to consider posting there, please check the site's policies & some related questions to judge for yourself first.

Comment: Agree with @JohnOmielan. Such questions often tend to become more than just a question-answer pattern. And we never had such questions as far as I remember. So, try asking one, and we shall together figure out if they would be appropriate, as a community :)

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com might be another place to ask such questions since AI as an academic discipline is considered on-topic there

Answer (score -1):

Just like almost all questions on data science stack exchange, the question to you suggest is on-topic on the statistics stack exchange, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history